# Unwanted height on container

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with a container for some text and a big space below it which I can't seem to remove. At first I thought it was because of the slideUp animation I gave it but when I remove that I have the same problem.

The position of the text is as I like it, when the page is scrolled all the way to the top (in the bottom right of the screen on desktop, and in the centre for mobile) but there is always a bunch of empty space to scroll down on the desktop view. Any idea how to remove it?

https://codepen.io/tomogram/pen/RwWMEEz

```
    <div class="content-container">
    <div class="cov-box">
        <p class="slide-up">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: black;
}


/* Screensize */


/* Mobile */

.cov-box {
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 15px;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}

.cov-box.move-right {
  opacity: 0%;
}

.slide-up {
  max-width: 600px;
}

@media (min-width: 559px) {
  .cov-box {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin: 0 30px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1150px) {
  .cov-box {
    width: 900px;
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    padding-top: 300px;
    right: 5px;
  }
  .slide-up {
    max-width: 700px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1250px) {
  .cov-box {
    font-size: 3rem;
    right: 30px;
  }
  .slide-up {
    max-width: 800px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1450px) {
  .cov-box {
    right: 100px;
    font-size: 3.5rem;
  }
  .slide-up {
    max-width: 900px;
  }
}


/* Header Bottom Ani */

.slide-up {
  animation-name: slideUp;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .3s;
  animation-delay: .3s;
  display: inline-block;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes slideUp {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(200%);
    opacity: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
    opacity: 100%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideUp {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(200%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
  <div class="cov-box">
    <p class="slide-up">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box;` to your elements

Comment: Much appreciated!